# react router nested components issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following code -

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                        <MainPage>
                            <Route exact path="user" component={Error}/>
                        </MainPage>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Right now MainPage is rendered for every Url , which i understand why,
but lets say that i want it to be render just for certain pages.
how can i wrap it in order to get it done?

Comment: Read the docs:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want to show MainPage for `/user` and `/member`, while `/anonymous` will be shown without MainPage:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/anonymous" component={Anonymous} />
                  <Route path="/" component={MainPage} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

class MainPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        .... // place your original code to print the `MainPage` here

        <Route path="/user" component={User}/>
        <Route path="/member" component={Member}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, writing Route of  /user and /member inside MainPage are also sending them as props.children to the MainPage component?

Comment: No, that's a different case. May I know what you need the routes (in the MainPage) for?